# Android AppWidget not receiving APPWIDGET_ENABLED intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-appwidget

I'm trying to create my first AppWidget using the AlarmManager class so that I can update more frequently than every 30 minutes.  I followed [this tutorial](http://buildmobile.com/alarmmanager-and-sleepy-android-apps/) as a basis for setting up my widget, but for some reason I cannot get the updates to begin properly.  It appears as I am never receiving any APPWIDGET_ENABLED intents, which would fire off the onEnabled event callback in my AppWidgetProvider.

Here is the manifest definition for my AppWidgetProvider:

```
    <receiver 
       android:name="com.myapp.android.appwidget.MarketTimingAppWidgetProvider"
       android:label="@string/appwidget_markettiming_label">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" /> 
            <action android:name="@string/appwidget_markettiming_updateintent" />           
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                   android:resource="@xml/appwidget_markettiming_info" />
    </receiver>
```

Here is the code for my AppWidgetProvider:

```
public class MarketTimingAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    Log.d("myLogger", "onUpdate");
    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {

        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        Log.d("myLogger", "Updating Widget: " + appWidgetId);
        updateWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);

    }

}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);

    Log.d("myLogger", "onEnabled running");
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 
                              1000, createClockIntent(context));   
}

public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    super.onDisabled(context);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(createClockIntent(context));
}

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    Log.d("myLogger", "Intent Received " + intent.getAction());
    String widgetIntent = context.getResources().getString(R.string.appwidget_markettiming_updateintent);

    // This code fires when my custom intent is received
    if(widgetIntent.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), getClass().getName());
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        int ids[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
        for(int appWidgetId: ids) {
            updateWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

}

private void updateWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget_markettiming);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_text, "Update: " +  
            DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
                    DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG).format(new Date()));

    // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

}

private PendingIntent createClockIntent(Context context) {
    String updateIntent = context.getResources().getString(R.string.appwidget_markettiming_updateintent);
    Log.d("myLogger", "my intent: " + updateIntent);
    Intent intent = new Intent(updateIntent);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return pendingIntent;
}
```

}

When I look in LogCat the only intent that is ever recieved by my onReceive method is the initial APPWIDGET_UPDATE intent, and the only callback ever executed is the onUpdate callback.  I've tried including the APPWIDGET_ENABLED intent in my appwidget intent-filter (although the docs tell me that this should be automatically received by my widget).  It didn't work.  Is there just something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your manifest. Action name in this element:

```
<action android:name="@string/appwidget_markettiming_updateintent" />
```

should be replaced by actual string, not the reference. So it should be something like this:

```
<action android:name="com.myapp.android.appwidget.action.MARKETTIMING_UPDATE" />
```

or whatever you have in your values/something.xml inside the `<string name="appwidget_markettiming_updateintent">` element.

The problem is that the BroadcastReceiver does not receives the broadcasts from AlarmManager. I've created a project with your code, replaced only this string in manifest (and added the appropriate value to values/strings.xml of course) and all works fine.

In addition, you may want to replace the second parameter of `alarmManager.setRepeating()` by just `System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000` and remove all those extra Calendar-related stuff.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not getting that intent for some reason, but at least its good to know that the code is structured like I thought it should be.  Does the TextView on the widget update every second?

Comment: No, just once. Now I go to sleep, but tomorrow will try to find time to look at the code in more detail. I am also currently learning to use the App Widgets, so will look for error together. :)

Comment: So I found that when I completely uninstalled the app from the emulator and then reinstalled it then the enabled event fired.  I guess that means I don't really understand when this Intent would be fired.  I thought it would be any time the first instance of a widget was added to the home screen.  If I removed it and added it again, I would imagine the enabled intent should be fired again.

Comment: You're right, I found that to be the source of my second issue.  I guess I was just trying to get too fancy in my config :). Although, I'm not entirely sure why that doesn't work like I would expect, since I can use string resources just like that everywhere else in the manifest.

Comment: I also don't know why that doesn't work in the same way as with other parts of manifest or with xml resources. On the other hand, the use of String constant in the code is simpler and more clear. So all the better. :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently uninstalling it from the emulator and then re-installing it did the trick.  Now when I add a widget the APPWIDGET_ENABLE intent is received, and when I remove it the APPWIDGET_DISABLED intent is fired like I would expect.  I'm still having an issue where the alarm manager does not actually fire off my custom Intent like I expect, but that's a separate issue I'll need to research.