# Sending an Intent from a Fragment to a Widget

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I am attempting to send an intent to update a home screen widget. I am unable to successfully send the intent and get the error

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.stream.homewidgets/com.stream.homewidgets.Parking}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

which comes from the `startActivity(intent)` line from my fragment.

I have looked at multiple Stack Overflow posts like the following:

- [Sending an update broadcast to an app widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663800/sending-an-update-broadcast-to-an-app-widget)
- [Android AppWidget not receiving APPWIDGET_ENABLED intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196347/android-appwidget-not-receiving-appwidget-enabled-intent)
- [Update Android Widget From Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073907/update-android-widget-from-activity)
- [Android: Unable to find explicit activity class… startActivity from a PreferenceActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946258/android-unable-to-find-explicit-activity-class-startactivity-from-a-preferen)

These have not quite been able to fix the issue for me, my code looks to be very similar.

Here is a snippet from my widget:

```
class Parking : AppWidgetProvider() {

    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, currentFloor)

            val intent = Intent(context, Parking::class.java)
            intent.action = AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds)

            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        }
    }

...

}
```

Here is a snippet from the calling fragment:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        ...

        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}

            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View?,
                position: Int,
                id: Long
            ) {

                context?.let {
                    val componentName = ComponentName(it, Parking::class.java)
                    val intent = Intent(context, Parking::class.java)
                    intent.action = AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE
                    val ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(it).getAppWidgetIds(componentName)
                    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }

        }
        return root
    }
}
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.stream.homewidgets">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <receiver android:name=".Parking">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/parking_info" />
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So I would like to be able to send an intent to update my widget. I am not sure how to solve this problem. My ".Parking" receiver is in the manifest although it is a receiver and not an activity. I do not know if there is a better way to broadcast an intent. If you know of a more correct way to send the intent to a widget, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tactically, you are trying to start an activity using a broadcast `Intent`, which will not work. Use `sendBroadcast()`, not `startActivity()`.

However, it would be faster and more efficient to just update the app widget directly, using `AppWidgetManager` and one of its `updateAppWidget()` methods. Your `Parking` class is merely a way for the system to request updates. If you wish to push an update, you can do that without involving `Parking`. Move your app-widget-update code into another class that can be used from both your `HomeFragment` and `Parking`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Can you help point me in the right direction for common conventions of separating the app-widget-update code into its own class?

Comment: @SpencerStream: App widgets are not widely implemented, and so I do not know what the common conventions might look like.